# Database of non-packager-specific drug information

Tags: data-request, openfda, medical

[DailyMed](http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/index.cfm) lets me look up the Structured Product Label files for various medications, and I know that I can download a database of those drug labels from DailyMed [here](http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/spl-resources.cfm).

The Structured Product Labels (SPLs) are all as supplied from the drug packager. That means none of them is suitable for displaying general information about the generic drug, like "ibuprofen" rather than "Advil" - even the generic listings you find will be for something like "Some-Company Ibuprofen". So, if I [search for gabapentin](http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/search.cfm?labeltype=all&query=gabapentin) I will find hundreds of results, but each of them makes reference to the company that makes the particular product. For instance, this is one of the [gabapentin medication guides](http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/drugInfo.cfm?setid=0936a88f-b569-49c4-951b-14e8f6273b53) found by that search, and it includes the name and phone number of the company that makes it, and further it only has information about capsule, not other forms. (By contrast, [this other manufacturer's product label](http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/medguide.cfm?setid=cff7de45-148b-4e96-88fd-6052bf75b5f7) talks about capsules, tablets and suspensions, since they make all those forms.)

I know you can find similar company-specific information on OpenFDA, such as this JSON document describing the same product as the first medication guide I linked to above; that has the same issues as the data straight from DailyMed.

So, is there a way through DailyMed or some other source to get information for a generic drug, without packager/manufacturer-specific information? To use an [RxNorm](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/rxnorm/overview.html) term, I'm looking for information about a "concept" rather than a "brand".

Answer (score 1):

Great question. There is an API for just this at: http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/RxNormAPIs.html

I am guessing that you want the `/drugs?name=<some name here>` endpoint, but there are a few from which to choose.

Best of luck.

Comment: Hans, thanks for the reply! Is there any place in the RxNorm API which has structured product label or Medication Guide information? I don't see an endpoint in the API that provides that - for instance, http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/drugs?name=cymbalta doesn't contain such information. Drugs@FDA also has structured product labels, but again they're all manufacturer-specific, as on http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.Overview&DrugName=GABAPENTIN